# What is this Icarus thing that comes with MbUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, automated-tests, mbunit

I've had to install **MbUnit** multiple times now and it keeps coming with something called the

`Gallilo Icarus GUI Test Runner`

I have tried using it thinking it was just an update to the MbUnit GUI but it won't detect my MbUnit tests and sometimes won't even open the assemblies properly.

Perhaps I'm just overlooking it but I haven't been able to find much of an answer on their website either except that it has something to do with a new testing platform.

Can someone give me a better explanation of what this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a blog entry [MbUnit v3 and Gallio alpha 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/astopford/archive/2007/11/30/mbunit%2Dv3%2Dand%2Dgallio%2Dalpha%2D1.aspx),

> So whats going on here, Gallio is a
>   neutral test platform that is an off
>   shoot from the work we had done on
>   MbUnit v3. Gallio is both a common
>   framework and a set of runners for
>   testing tools. MbUnit v3 uses Gallio
>   as its native test platform, Gallio
>   can also as Jeff mentions run MbUnit,
>   NUnit and XUnit.net tests. For both
>   migration purposes and to help improve
>   how you are using your existing test
>   framework we hope this will prove
>   useful. We still have a lot of work to
>   do but make no secrets of what we are
>   up to, [check out our road map.](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/wiki/Roadmap) I do
>   want to draw attention to the work we
>   are doing with our new runners.
>   Starting with Icarus, our new GUI.

So, "Gallio is a neutral test platform" and "Icarus, [their] new GUI."